# How to pass cognito identity id to backend

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

I would like to use Api gateway as http proxy of my API restful.
I use Cognito to authorize the access to the API gateway as well as my endopoint. 
I think to use the cognito identity id to identify the user but I don't know how pass this context variable to the backend for each request (GET, POST, PUT...)

Can you help me?

Thank you
Agostino

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a request mapping template and use "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId" to get the cognito identity ID.

i.e.

`{
"cognito-identity" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId"
}`

This will send the identity ID in the request body.

You could also send in a HTTP parameter by using "context.identity.cognitoIdentityId" in your parameter mapping expression.

See also:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

Comment: I can't find the way to add a parameter to the request in the integration request. I know how do it into the body but not as parameter

Comment: This is supported for HTTP integrations only. If you're using a Lambda backend, you're limited to the request body.