# How to access Cognito identity from an EC2-hosted application without fronting API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

**The problem**

At a high-level, I want to authorize certain functionality in my application based on the user's specific Cognito-provided identity.

More specifically, I would like to do this within my EC2-hosted Tomcat application, without relying on API Gateway.

**An example**

For example, my RESTful service might have resources at `helloworld.com/tastyTreats/foo` and `/tastyTreats/bar`. I only want to allow write-access to those resources when the `tastyTreat` is listed in the database as being owned by a particular Cognito identifier.

Say that database looks like this:

```
{"TreatName":"foo", "Owner":"Alice"},

{"TreatName":"bar", "Owner":"Bob"},

...
```

So, the user identified by Cognito as *Bob* should have write access to `helloworld.com/tastyTreats/bar` but should [hit a 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) when accessing `/tastyTreats/foo`.

I would like to be able to perform this authorization within my EC2 instance for its (essentially) unlimited flexibility. And, if it's feasible, I would like to avoid the requirement to roll API Gateway -- it's a very small application and I'd like to keep things as simple as possible.

**Other AWS services that provide this functionality**

Other services beside straight EC2 provide the ability to alter behavior based on the actual identity:

- API Gateway seems to allow access to this identity [in the mapping template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125500/how-to-pass-cognito-identity-id-to-backend).
- You can more generally [customize a policy based on this identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25703140/iam-policy-for-s3-folder-access-based-on-cognito-id), but this feature seems limited in its ability to transform the identity.

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you using a Cognito Identity Pool, you won't be able to do this on your own from an EC2 instance. That is only available through other AWS services like the API Gateway identity attribute. If you're using Cognito User Pools, then that is a standard JWT/JWK implementation (using OIDC I believe) so you can implement that yourself from the EC2 instance.